# Correct pronunciation of graphicx?

Tags: graphics, pronunciation

I know that this question may be not in the main stream, but it is the matter of communication.

We have LaTeX graphic packages `graphics` (`s` as standard) and `graphicx` (`x` as extended). I am thinking that the former should be pronunciated  `/ˈɡræfɪks/`, but what about the latter?

Comment: I pronounce them the same `:)` I think only David Carlisle is qualified to offer a legitimate answer.

Comment: new one and the old one ;)

Comment: @WillRobertson http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16591972#16591972

Comment: @percusse but which is new and which is old (think carefully before answering that:-)

Comment: I think you should say graphics as you normally do but then make a wild gesture with your hand, showing that you are "street" and for that reason will write it with a X

Comment: This question reminded me that, sadly, I have never had an occasion to say any LaTeX related word except "LaTeX" :(

Comment: @MartinH -- but that doesn't work if you're talking on the telephone.  ("graphic-ex", while not elegant, is at least comprehensible under such conditions.)

Comment: Graphics-ex sounds a lot like graphic-sex.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I chose `x` originally to give the option of pronouncing it as `s`, the same as `graphics` but then you end up pronouncing them as “graphics-with-an-ess” and “graphics-with-an-ex” which is a bit of a mouthful, so normally (if I have to pronounce them at all) I'd say “graphics” and “graphic-ex”.  But there is no “correct” pronunciation, just as with the pronunciation of LaTeX itself, the official documentation is deliberately vague on pronunciation and many variants are in use.

Comment: How about `graphic` + `eXtreme`? wooohooo `:)`