# Pronunciation of biblatex and biber

Tags: pronunciation

I wonder how I shall pronounce `biblatex` and `biber`. Shall I pronounce bi as in bite or bi as in bit?(although in case of biber I prefer to say bi as in bite because it reminds me of that canadian guy). 
I ask because I have no one to talk about Latex and if there is s/he is not expert in Latex and I am solely dependent to this forum and books and package documentations.

I hope this way of editing meets the requirements of tex.se question template.

Comment: Could you please not vote to this question?

Comment: I think it is time to develop the `imbibetex` package...bottoms up!

Comment: "Could you please not vote to this question?" Why? :S I mean, I have a feeling this question will be closed as it's very, very broad, flirting with off-topicality however narrowed down and arguably opinion-based, but why do *you* not want people to vote on your own question :S :S

Comment: I didn't just mean upvotes. I know it's to broad but I wanted to know the correct pronunciations and not up or down votes. It might seem to you as something of minor priority but while I'm reading and encounter these names not knowing the correct pronunciation disrupts the smooth reading of the text. Also because I might talk about it with my friends and classmates I don't want to be the origin of wrong pronunciation in my language.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Shall I read it as I am bibi tex as a sarcastic variation of baby?

Comment: I actually intended it as an imperative to drink alcohol (imbibe) while TeXing.  But the example proves your whole point about the ambiguity of package name pronunciation.

Comment: @nima I don't think it's necessarily minor, I learned biology out of a book and I know what it's like to squirm uncomfortably when I need to pronounce a name like Saccharomyces cerevisiae for somebody else, I'm just not sure this is the place to get answers. Sometimes package documentation come with pronunciation tips. But, with the voting, voting is an important part of stackexchange. If you yourself think the question is such a bad fit you don't want any upvotes, then I don't think it's unfair to say you shouldn't ask.

Comment: If, however, you think it's borderline, then why not let the community decide whether they want the question to stand by voting in the normal way. you may get a surprising number of upvotes and it'll help you and us all decide what questions belong here. If, on the other hand, you're trying to stave off down votes for a question you think is bad, well I don't think that's really cricket. And anyway, downvotes aren't supposed to be a simple telling off, we don't tend to downvote below -1 here, it's a way of reflecting the community's thoughts about a question and of learning and teaching.

Comment: I'll start the trend and upvote.

Comment: Steven is right it is off-topic and I was not afraid of negative points really. I feared upvotes for an off-topic question but I needed to ask.

Comment: Related: [Correct pronunciation of `graphicx`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191505/5764); [How is TikZ meant to be pronounced? “tiks”, “tikz” or “tik-zee”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212355/5764)

Comment: I think you're better off asking this in [chat], as there may be many interpretations rather than official pronunciations (see the above related links as an example).

Comment: @Werner thanks. that's good and I think the most practical solution to my problem.

Comment: these particular packages all have to do with bibliographies, and in such a situation, the logical pronunciation is the same as for "biblio" -- rhymes with "bit".  you have my sympathy for having to guess about something you have only read from a written source.  i keep finding words that i'm quite familiar with on paper have pronunciations different from what i guessed ... more than 50 years ago.  so don't be afraid to ask.

Comment: I would choose @Werner 's answer as best. I do not like to narrow it because I think werner's answer is a good one to a broad problem. So is this convincing enough so that werner post it as answer and I choose it?